# Integral of Gamma Functions

Tags: number-theory, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, special-functions

Is the following integral able to be expressed by closed form or special functions?

$$\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(\frac{\Gamma(at+b)}{\Gamma(ct+b)}\right)\frac{dt}{t}$$, for any non-negative numbers $a,b,c$.

Appreciate!

Comment: MSE is a proper forum for such type questions.

Comment: Okay, should I delete it?

Comment: I think yes. Also you may repost it at MSE.

Comment: you cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center??

Comment: The Robert's answer is simply wrong: Maple does not perform it.

Comment: Got it! I revised it.

Comment: I don't understand why you accept the Robert's answer. I repeat the performed result is not a closed-form expression (look in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression). I repeat that your question is for MSE, not for MO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maple expresses it as
$$ \ln  \left( a \right) \ln  \left( b \right) -1/2\, \left( \ln  \left( 
a \right)  \right) ^{2}-{\it polylog} \left( 2,-{\frac {b}{a}}
 \right) -\ln  \left( c \right) \ln  \left( b \right) +1/2\, \left( 
\ln  \left( c \right)  \right) ^{2}+{\it polylog} \left( 2,-{\frac {b
}{c}} \right) -a\gamma+c\gamma-\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{2k
} \left( 2\,\ln  \left(  \left( k+b \right) ^{-1} \right) \ln  \left( 
a \right) k-2\,\ln  \left(  \left( k+b \right) ^{-1} \right) \ln 
 \left( c \right) k+ \left( \ln  \left( a \right)  \right) ^{2}k-
 \left( \ln  \left( c \right)  \right) ^{2}k+2\,{\it polylog} \left( 2
,-{\frac {k+b}{a}} \right) k-2\,{\it polylog} \left( 2,-{\frac {k+b}{c
}} \right) k-2\,a+2\,c \right) }
$$

EDIT: Here is the appropriate Maple command:

```
int(log(GAMMA(a*t+b)/GAMMA(c*t+b))/t,t=0..1) assuming a>0, b>0, c>0;
```

I would be interested to know what command user64494 tried.

Comment: Thank you very much! What is the function "polylog"? I used Mathematica yesterday but it seems like can not be expressed closed form. I am just curious is there any good reference about this like how to treat this integral to be closed form or special functions.

Comment: I wonder which form, the original integral or the truncated series, would require less computational complexity to achieve the same numerical precision.

Comment: I can't reproduce the above in Maple 2017.3: the unevaluated integral is returned. Also the the expression which includes a series is not s closed-form expression (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression).

Comment: For the polylog function as used by Maple, see [here](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=polylog)

Comment: I used int(ln(GAMMA(a*t+b)/GAMMA(c*t+b))/t, t = 1 .. 2) assuming a > 0, b > 0, c > 0; I do confirm that int(log(GAMMA(a*t+b)/GAMMA(c*t+b))/t, t = 1 .. 2) assuming a > 0, b > 0, c > 0; produces the result from the Robert's answer. The misunderstanding was caused by Maple weakness. However, the result presented by Robert is not a closed-form expression.

Comment: @RobertIsrael


I see  Thank you!

Comment: @user64494 Thank you too!